# Blinding to mask private key operations

Tags: factoring, blinding

Blinding is often used to mask private key operations when the underlying problem is integer factorization. For example, it's used in both RSA and Rabin-Williams signature schemes. This presumes integer operations are not constant time.

I have two questions:

- Is blinding used in schemes other than integer factorization?
- Are there other options to guard the private key against timing attacks available to software implementations on commodity hardware?

The reason I ask is Evgeny Sidorov's [Breaking the Rabin-Williams digital signature system implementation in the Crypto++ library](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/368) (*a.k.a.* CVE-2015-2141). There was a bad interaction with the blinding value and Jacobi requirements on *p*, *q*, which resulted in a private key recovery.

One of the suggested remediations was to disable blinding. I'm trying to gauge the impact of doing it in libraries like OpenSSL and Crypto++, and how much needs to change if blinding is optional. (It is already optional in OpenSSL, but not Crypto++).

Comment: [These](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/srds2009/escs2009_submission_Gopal.pdf) [links](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15864/23623) [may](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Montgomery.27s_ladder_technique) [be](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/16515/23623) related to 2).

Comment: Thanks SEJPM. That's a good point about other problems (in particular, the DH problem rather than FF problem).

Answer (score 1):

1) Blinding has been used, for example, to design a version of El Gamal encryption that is resilient to certain side-channel attacks --- see [PK] and the references therein.

2) The goal of the field of leakage-resilient cryptography is to model and study (from a theoretical perspective) what security can be guaranteed against side-channel attacks (including e.g., timing attacks). See [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/302.pdf) recent survey or [this](https://windowsontheory.org/2012/08/09/on-leakage-resilient-cryptography/) excellent blog post for more details on the type of models that are being considered.

[PK]: Pietrzak and Kiltz. [Leakage Resilient ElGamal Encryption](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2010/6477599/6477599.pdf)